# New Zealand - resident work visa for spouses

Tags: working-visas, new-zealand

Being IT engineers, My spouse and I both fall in the skilled migrant category for New Zealand.  If we both intend to work, should we file separate applications with each one of us as principal applicant? If yes, we have 2 kids aged 8 & 11, what will be the best approach - Should 1 of us file for both kids as dependents or should each one of us file for 1 kid?